# Python pandas combine two dataframe into one based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

df1 columns --> `['CID', 'Name', 'Voucher', 'Issued']`

df2 columns --> `['CID', 'sec', 'Address', 'City', 'ZipCode', 'PhoneNumber', 'Country']`

Using `CID` on `df1`, i would like to check if it's found on `df2['CID']` and get the full row values.

So the final output columns should be:

`['CID', 'Name', 'Voucher', 'Issued', 'sec', 'Address', 'City', 'ZipCode', 'PhoneNumber', 'Country']`

I'm dealing with large file `5gb`, what should be the most perfect solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the combination:

```py
# If you want to keep all the rows of df1:
df1.merge(df2, on=['CID'], how='left')

# If you want to keep only the rows that match:
df1.merge(df2, on=['CID'], how='inner')
```

About the size:
If your dataset is that big and can't be stored in memory you could try casting your features into lighter datatypes (like int8 and float16) when possible before merging.

Comment: Thanks Mate, it works well. Thanks for the good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would think `pd.merge()` would do it.

Something like:

```
df_final = df1.merge(df2, on='CID', how='left')
```

Comment: Thank you. Keep up the good work. Next time please include explanation